# To get mount point

Tags: powershell

I need a Powershell command to get mount point of a NAS drives.

I tried below command, however, not sure it's correct or not.

```
gwmi win32_mappedlogicaldisk | select name, providername
```

Also, I am unaware of the NAS drives which I need to find and get the mount point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the mount points on the Windows OS consider reading the `DeviceID` property from [win32_mappedlogicaldisk](http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/win32_mappedlogicaldisk/) or you could use [Get-PSDrive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psdrive?view=powershell-6) too perhaps.

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Win32_MappedLogicalDisk](http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/win32_mappedlogicaldisk/)

  > **DeviceID**
  >
  > *`Data type String`*
  >
  > DeviceID is an address or other identifying information to uniquely
  >   name the logical device.
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **Name**
  >
  > *`Data type String`*
  >
  > The Name property defines the label by which the object is known. When
  >   subclassed, the Name property can be overridden to be a Key property.

Comment: @Praveen Verify the per the `providername` in the value of that field it should match the IP address or DNS host name of the NAS server. Whatever entries can be identified at this level related to the NAS server will also contain the mount points it uses to mount to those resources.

Comment: Yes got it with admin rights, provider name would be mount path, right?

Comment: The mount point will be the drive letter the OS assigns to access the UNC resource in this case. The `ProviderName` property is the UNC path I suppose so that will be the NAS server and share for you. [*"The ProviderName property indicates the network path name to the logical device"*](http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/win32_mappedlogicaldisk/)

Comment: Oh, yes that's the path the mount actually mounts to so yes.